# Mailgun - Attach a file in phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, mailgun

I am trying to make a application using phantomjs which requires mailgun service to send email. Since there is no official mailgun phantomjs library, I am facing some troubles with attaching files in the emails. The email is dispatched successfully but I dont see any attachment to it.

Here is the code:

```
function ObjToQs(obj) {
    var str = "";
    for (key in obj) {
        str += key + '=' + obj[key] + '&';
    }
    str = str.slice(0, str.length - 1);
    return str;
}=
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    url = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org/messages',
    data = {
        from: "Ganesh <mail@gmail.com>",
        to: "email@gmail.com",
        subject: "subject!",
        text: "Body",
        attachment: '/path/test.txt'
    };
console.log(ObjToQs(data));
page.customHeaders = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('api:key-xxxxxxxx')};
page.open(url, 'post', ObjToQs(data), function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('FAIL to load the log');
        console.log(status);
    } else {
        console.log('Log success');

        var result = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.body.innerText;
        });

        console.log("log Result: " + result);
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you -- it's a NodeJS lib for mailgun: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js